# Fetching data from the list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with location and quantity, like

```
{'loc1': 1000.0,'loc2': 500.0, 'loc3': 200.0,'loc4': 100.0,'loc5': 50.0, }
```

Now when i'll make a order the scenario should be like below,

- for `150 quantity`  it should take product from `loc5` and `loc4`
- for `210 quantity`  it should take product from `loc3` and `loc5`
- for `1777 quantity`  it should take product from `loc1` and `loc2` and `loc3` and `loc4`
- for `530 quantity`  it should take product from `loc2` and `loc5`.

I don't know how achieve such kind of condition, can anyone sort it out??

Comment: what is the logic behind the order scenarios ?

Comment: @karthikr: Minimal fulfillment.

Comment: This is the [change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem), e.g. knapsack problem to minimize the total weight, but with dictionaries.

Comment: @karthikr i am using for loop to check qty but it's not helping..

Comment: @Magsol Thanks for the link, this is what I am asking for, but I am not maths expert,

Comment: You should start by formalizing the condition you wish to fulfill. (because in most cases, take from loc1 is sufficient.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the quantities in a list, sorted. [Use `bisect` to find an appropriate quantity.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) Calculate if the lower quantities can fulfill, and if not pick the next higher quantity. Subtract the selected quantity. If still greater than 0, go back to the `bisect` step.

**EDIT:**

```
import bisect

qtys = [50, 100, 200, 500, 1000]

def sack(amt, qtys=qtys):
  res = set()
  while amt > 0:
    pivot = bisect.bisect(qtys, amt)
    if sum(qtys[:pivot]) >= amt:
      amt -= qtys[pivot - 1]
      res.add(pivot - 1)
    else:
      if sum(qtys[:pivot + 1]) < amt:
        raise ValueError('Not enough items to fill the sack')
      res.add(pivot)
      amt -= qtys[pivot]
  return res

print sack(150)
print sack(210)
print sack(1777)
print sack(530)
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer, by looking on the votes on your answer it's seems a solution of my question, but as a beginner I don't know how to achieve..

Comment: @Heliconia: Bring your questions up, one at a time.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Maybe you could include one example about how to use bisect for this case...

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_combination(d,val): 
    """(dict,int)->list
    Given a dict with values as numbers, returns the combination of keys whose values sums up to "val"
    In case no values form a perfect sum, picks up the next best case
    """
    new_list = sorted(d.items(),key=lambda y: y[1],reverse=True)
    result = []
    while val > 0:
        min_item = ''
        for item in new_list: 
            if item[0] in result: 
                continue
            new_diff = abs(val - item[1])
            if not min_item or new_diff <= min_diff:
                min_item = item[0]
                min_diff = new_diff
                min_val = item[1]
        result.append(min_item)
        val = val - min_val
    return result
```

Given

```
d={'loc2': 500.0, 'loc3': 200.0, 'loc1': 1000.0, 'loc4': 100.0, 'loc5': 50.0}
```

This gives

```
>>> combi.find_combination(d,150)
['loc4', 'loc5']
>>> combi.find_combination(d,210)
['loc3', 'loc5']
>>> combi.find_combination(d,1777)
['loc1', 'loc2', 'loc3', 'loc4']
>>> combi.find_combination(d,530)
['loc2', 'loc5']
>>> combi.find_combination(d,160)
['loc3']
```

Must point out that it is (horribly) inefficient

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried the logic but it will break on if the qty is more then the available qty, eg 1888,

Comment: Yes in that case it would look for best fit (which would be 2000). Even if weights are `1000,400,300,200` and you set `val=900`, it would pick up `1000` rather than `400+300+200`

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm might help you!

```
def greedy(amount, denoms):
    result = []
    while (amount > 0):
        print amount, denoms, result
        if (amount >= denoms[0]):
            num = amount // denoms[0]
            amount -= (num * denoms[0])
            result.append([denoms[0], num])
        denoms = denoms[1:]
    return result

print greedy(100, [25,10,5,1])
print ""
print greedy(100, [10,5,1])
print ""
print greedy(100, [5,1])
print ""
print greedy(100, [1])
print ""
print greedy(47, [25,10,5,1])
```

And the out put will be

```
100 [25, 10, 5, 1] []
[[25, 4]]

100 [10, 5, 1] []
[[10, 10]]

100 [5, 1] []
[[5, 20]]

100 [1] []
[[1, 100]]

47 [25, 10, 5, 1] []
22 [10, 5, 1] [[25, 1]]
2 [5, 1] [[25, 1], [10, 2]]
2 [1] [[25, 1], [10, 2]]
[[25, 1], [10, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though i think Ignacio and Atul answers are better if you wanna stick with the dictionary you can use a while loop that subtracts the quantity,

```
#qnt,the quantity you have

dic={'loc1': 1000.0,'loc2': 500.0, 'loc3': 200.0,'loc4': 100.0,'loc5': 50.0, }

dic2= {'loc1':0,'loc2':0,'loc3':0,'loc4':0,'loc5':0} 
while qnt>0:
        if qnt>=dic['loc1']:
             qnt-= dic['loc1']
             dic2['loc1']+=1
        elif qnt>=dic['loc2']:
             qnt-= dic['loc2']
             dic2['loc2']+=1
        elif qnt>=dic['loc3']:
             qnt-= dic['loc3']
             dic2['loc3']+=1
        elif qnt>=dic['loc4']:
             qnt-= dic['loc4']
             dic2['loc4']+=1
        elif qnt>0:
             qnt-= dic['loc5']
             dic2['loc5']+=1

        else:break
print dic2
```